# Arithmetic Sequence - find the biggest value

Tags: sequences-and-series

If $x$, $y$, $z$ and $t$ form an arithmetic sequence and $x + y + z + t = 26$ and $xt/yz=11/20$, then which one of $x$, $y$, $z$ or $t$ will be having the biggest value?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Approach the problem with the definition of an arithmetic sequence. The first number is $x$, the second number is $x+a = y$ for some $a$, etc.

Comment: Since both equations are symmetric in $x,t$ (i.e. you can exchange the values of $x$ and $t$ without affecting the equations) and also symmetric in $y,z$, it is impossible to tell which term in greatest from the information given. At best you can conclude that *one of* $x$ and $t$ has the greatest value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the terms be $x,x+d,x+2d,x+3d$. Then:
$$\begin{cases}4x+6d=26\\ \frac{x(x+3d)}{(x+d)(x+2d)}=\frac{11}{20}\end{cases} \Rightarrow \begin{cases}x=\frac{13-3d}{2} \\ 9x^2+27xd-22d^2=0\end{cases} \Rightarrow \begin{cases}x_1=2;x_2=11 \\ d_1=3; d_2=-3\end{cases} \Rightarrow \\
AP1: 2,5,8,11.\\
AP2: 11,8,5,2.$$